# Determining the reflection matrix for line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, reflection

Question:

> Determine the matrix for reflection in the line 2 −  = 0 in ℝ2
>
> Hint: split this transformation into simpler ones, and combine the
>   result using matrix multiplication.

I thought about it this way.

> y = 2x.

If I scale all y values down by 1/2 with the matrix,

> \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 1/2 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}

And do reflection as if y=x,

> \begin{pmatrix}
>         0 & 1 \\
>         1 & 0 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}

And scale the y values back up by 2,

> \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 2 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}

If I multiply the matrices in the same order, I should get the reflection matrix for the line 2x-y=0
However, the result I had below was not correct.

> \begin{pmatrix}
>         0 & 2 \\
>         1/2 & 0 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}

What is wrong about my approach?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525082/reflection-across-a-line

Comment: [Hans Lundmark’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497110/265466) identifies one of the mistakes you’re making. Try rotations instead.

Comment: @amd What do you mean by trying rotation, is it relevant with this question?

Comment: You tried decomposing the reflection into $M^{-1}RM$, where $R$ is a simple reflection in a coordinate axis, with $M$ as a scaling transform. That fails for the reason given by Hand Lundmark. Rotations don’t affect relative angles, though, so try finding a suitable rotation to use as $M$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling one axis but not the other will distort angles.

(Also, your result is obviously wrong, since you didn't get an orthogonal matrix.)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t  know why you are making it more difficult. You can use the projection of the unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ onto the $(1,2)$.

the image of $x$ onto $a$ is $a' = 2(a^Tx)a/(a^Ta) - x$. Using this in your problem, for the image of $x = (1,0)$, $a = (1,2)$. So we have $a^tx = 1$, $a^T a = 5$ which gives $a' = 2/5(1,2) - (1,0) = (-3/5, 2/5)$. This $a'$ is your first column of the reflection matrix. To find the second column, find $(0,1)'$.

Comment: The OP isn’t the one making it “more difficult.” It’s whoever created the assignment :)